# Multiple images are uploading in server folder but only one record is inserted in mysql

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, symfony-forms, symfony-3.3

The below code is successfully uploading mutiple images to web/images/album but the only one record is updated in mysql.
So while displaying the images only one image is being displayed.
Since I am new to symfony I don't know how to do.
Can any one guide me how to get all the name of the images and insert their names in mysql??

Entity

```
class album  
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="albumName", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $albumName;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="imageName", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $imageName;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set albumName
 *
 * @param string $albumName
 *
 * @return album
 */
public function setAlbumName($albumName)
{
    $this->albumName = $albumName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get albumName
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAlbumName()
{
    return $this->albumName;
}

/**
 * Set imageName
 *
 * @param string $imageName
 *
 * @return album
 */
public function setImageName($imageName)
{
    $this->imageName = $imageName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get imageName
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getImageName()
{
    return $this->imageName;
}
 }
```

Form

```
     $builder->add('albumName', TextType::class)
               ->add('imageName', FileType::class, array(
                'multiple' => true,
                'data_class' => null
            ))
               ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Submit',        'attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')));
```

Controller

```
  public function indexAction(Request $request) {

    $albumMember = new album();

    $galleryView = $this->createForm(imageUpload::class, $albumMember);
    $galleryView->handleRequest($request);
    if ($galleryView->isSubmitted() && $galleryView->isValid()) {

        /**
         * @var UploadedFile $file
         */
        $file = $albumMember->getImageName();
        foreach ($file as $count) {
            $fileName = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $count->guessExtension();

            $count->move(
                    $this->getParameter('image_directory'), $fileName
            );
            $albumMember->setImageName($fileName);

            $albumName = $galleryView['albumName']->getData();
            $albumMember->setAlbumName($albumName);
        }
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($albumMember);
        $em->flush();

        $this->addFlash('notice', 'Images Added');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('createGallery');
    }

    return $this->render('admin/galleryView.html.twig', [
                'galleryView' => $galleryView->createView()
    ]);
}
```

Comment: ‘setImageName‘ is in the foreach loop so gets overridden. Read about collections.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you only have one column called image name for each album, when in fact you need to have multiple images. You have to make a manyToOne relationship
https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html

You make an image class and the album class, with many images mapping to one album, and then you create multiple image objects for each image and set them to said album...

Answer (score 0):

For how you defined your `Album` entity it would expect only one image and not many of them. You should revisit your entity for using a one-to-many association between an `Album` and many `Image` in it.

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/** @Entity */
class Album
{
    // ...
    /**
     * One Album has Many Images.
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Image", mappedBy="album")
     */
    private $images;
    // ...

    public function __construct() {
        $this->images = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}

/** @Entity */
class Image
{
    // ...
    /**
     * Many Images have One Album.
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Album", inversedBy="images")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="album_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $album;
    // ...
}
```

Then when processing the request from the form you should add the images to the ArrayCollection. Something like this:

```
$album->getImages->add($image)
```

of course you'll have getters/setters for that.

See more about Doctrine associations [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) and [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html).